# How can I login the user manually in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Here is my code:

```
public function register_and_login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator_short($request->all())->validate();

    $user = User::where('cell_phone', $request->cell_phone)->first();

    // already registered
    if ( is_null($user) ) {
        $user_id = User::create([
                    'name' => $request->name,
                    'cell_phone' => $request->cell_phone,
                    'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
        ]);
    } else {
        $user_id = $user->id;
    }

    $this->guard()->login($user_id);

    dd('user is logged in now');
}
```

My code works when the user isn't registered so far and we create it. But when he has registered already, my code throws this error:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure the `User` model extends `Authenticatable`:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable
```

Also, use `auth()` helper or `Auth::` facade:

```
$user = User::create(['name' => $request->name,
    'cell_phone' => $request->cell_phone,
    'password' => bcrypt($request->password)
]);
auth()->login($user);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#other-authentication-methods

Comment: The `User` model is exactly like what you described.

Comment: Also for your information, I've added `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;` at the top of my controller. I guess probable the error is because of it

Comment: @MartinAJ if you changed `->login($user_id);` to `->login($user);` as I've shown and `User` model extends the `Authenticatable`, this will work. If you're getting an error message after these changes, it's definitely a different one. Please show it.

Comment: I don't get any error. But login doesn't happen. the result of `auth()->login($user);` is `null`.

Comment: @MartinAJ try to do `auth()->login($user, true)` and put `dd(auth()->user())` after this line. It will show you `User` object if user was authenticated and `null` if not.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused now ..! The result of `dd(auth()->user()->id);` is `33` (the id of the user). But still I cannot access home page because of not being logged in. Odd.

Comment: @MartinAJ it's not related to this code. Check the logic you use to check if the user was authenticated or not (middleware, routes etc).

Answer (score 0):

Change your else part to -

```
else {
    $user_id = $user;
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: have you changed to `$user_id = $user`??

Answer (score 0):

The login function is not asking you for an integer id, it's asking for an Authenticable. In any default Laravel application, that's usually the User Model.

The problem lies in your else statement. You don't need to set $user_id to the id of the user you loaded when checking the cell number. You just need to use the user you loaded. Based on your logic, you don't even need the else statement.

A possible separate issue with your logic,is that you're checking to see if the cell number exists, and if it does, logging in *that* user, not the user that your doing the check for. This may be desired behaviour, but it doesn't seem like.

```
public function register_and_login(Request $request)
{
  $this->validator_short($request->all())->validate();

  $user = User::where('cell_phone', $request->cell_phone)->first();

  // already registered
  if ( is_null($user) ) {
    $user = User::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'cell_phone' => $request->cell_phone,
                'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
    ]);
  }

 $this->guard()->login($user);

}
```